# How to get mysqli instance recognised in functions?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm in the process of upgrading from mysql to mysqli.

All my mysql code was procedural, and I'd now like to convert to OOP, as most mysqli examples online are in OOP.

The problem I'm having is that, with mysql, once I had set up a connection, I never had to inject that connection into any functions as arguments for mysql to be accessible in the function.

Here is my old connection code:

```
$location = "localhost";
$user = "rogerRamjet"; 
$pass = "bestPassInTheWorld"; 
$dbName = "myDBName";

$link = mysql_connect($location, $user, $pass);
if (!$link) {
    die("Could not connect to the database.");
}

mysql_select_db("$dbName") or die ("no database");
```

And an example function that has access to the mysql connection, without $link needing to be injected into the function:

```
function getUser($data)
{
    $data=mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    $error = array('status'=>false,'userID'=>-1);   
    $query = "SELECT `user_id`, `user_email` FROM `myTable` WHERE `data`='$data'";  
    if ($result = mysql_query($query))  
    {             
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC); 
        if ($row['user_id']!="")
        {
            return array( 'status'=>true, 'userID'=>$row['user_id'], 'email'=>$row['user_email'] );
        }
        else return $error;           
    }
    else return $error; 
}
```

And here's my new mysqli connection:

```
$mysqli=new MySQLi($location, $user, $pass, $dbName);
```

So, to upgrade the first line in the above function, I'd need:

```
$data = $mysqli->real_escape_string($data);
```

But that throws the error:

```
Undefined variable: mysqli
```

Does this mean that for any function needing access to $mysqli, I need to inject $mysqli as an argument into it, or is there a way for it to be accessible the way mysql is without injection?

I know I need to move to prepared statements, but this is just so I can get my head around mysqli basics.

Comment: Check out php.net's article on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crude solution would be `global $mysqli;` as first line of your function. But as hsan wrote, read about PHP variable scope

Comment: Although `global` will help, it's not advised to be used, as it required the variable exists, and if it doesn't your application won't work. I'd build a class which makes a connection, does its stuff and disconnects.

Comment: Thanks guys. Why is it that mysql never needed to be injected, or set as a global?

Comment: Further - it's accessible without doing anything except setting up a mysql connection. How?

Answer (score 1):

Making the variable global is bad practice. The singleton pattern solves the issue of needing to share one instance of an object throughout an application lifecycle. Consider using a Singleton.

Comment: Using a singleton is the same global state, just from the different angle